When is the triangle inequality for Lebesgue integrals an equality?
The triangle inequality for integrals says
$$\left|\int_{\Omega}fd\mu\right|\leq \int \left|f\right|d\mu.$$
My question is when this inequality is an equality? Is it sufficient that f is non-negative?

Yes, it is sufficient that $f$ is non-negative. In fact, equality holds iff $f$ is either

non-negative except on a set of measure zero, or
non-positive except on a set of measure zero.

To see why, consider the decomposition of $f$ into its positive and negative parts. That is, write $f = f^+ - f^-$, where $f^+, f^- \geq 0$ (we have $f^+=\max(f,0)$, and $f^-=\max(-f,0)$). Then
$$\left| \int_\Omega f \right| = \left| \int_\Omega f^+ - \int_\Omega f^- \right|,$$
and
$$\int_\Omega |f| = \int_\Omega f^+ + \int_\Omega f^-.$$
Setting $a=\int_\Omega f^+$ and $b=\int_\Omega f^-$, we're now just asking when $|a-b|=a+b$ for $a,b \geq 0$. This only happens when either $a$ or $b$ is zero, which corresponds to $f^+=0$ a.e. or $f^-=0$ a.e.

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1
